# TIFFReadDirectory Warnings when reading GeoTiff with QPixmap::load( )

Tags: c++, qt, tiff, geotiff

I have a geotiff file which I am loading into a QPixmap with QPixmap::load( ). I get the following warnings printed to the console a bunch of times. However, direct use of libtiff opens it without warnings.

Any ideas on how to alleviate these unsightly warnings in QT?

```
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 34736 (0x87b0) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 34736 (0x87b0) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered.
```

Thanks!

Comment: After looking into it more, they are actually geotiff tags. However, there doesn't appear to be an easy way to disable the warnings, since QT by default reports all warnings from the underlying libtiff library. It's not a big deal, but it is a bit unsightly.

Answer (score 2):

These are custom tags which can be defined with the libtiff library:
http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/addingtags.html

They are probably EXIF tags:
http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif.html

These are the known tags to libtiff:
http://trac.imagemagick.org/browser/tiff/trunk/libtiff/tiff.h#L148

Since the new definitions include type and count, you may guess, what these tags mean. Also you can run exiftool to examine unknown TIFF tags:
 $ exiftool -htmldump sample.tif > /tmp/dump.html; firefox /tmp/dump.html