# Read tags encoded in tiff file

Tags: c++, qt

I have a tiff image that also contains some geographical information (GeoTiff) that I am reading in Qt.

After reading it, Qt throws some warnings similar to these

```
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered.
```

Is there any way to read the contents of these tags in Qt?

Addressing the possible duplicate issue - I too ran across that question but the issue there was with the tags themselves. The OP thought they are unsightly and wanted them suppressed. What I want to do is to actually read them.

Also I did try using **textKeys()** just in case, it does not read them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TIFFReadDirectory Warnings when reading GeoTiff with QPixmap::load( )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127160/tiffreaddirectory-warnings-when-reading-geotiff-with-qpixmapload)

Comment: StackExchange does change tracking for you. Please do not put "Edit" headers into the question. Instead, edit in your questions so that they flow with the rest of the text.

Comment: SUGGESTION: 1) See if [libgeotiff](http://trac.osgeo.org/geotiff/) works better than Qt with your particular files, 2) If so, use libgeotiff to generate an image, and Qt to display it.

Comment: @KubaOber I kept doing it intentionally until today. Thanks for the suggestion though, I will comply.

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes I did also build that library, I was just wondering if there exists some trick that would allow me to read the values without it. I would be not that hard (time consuming maybe) to write my own parser in Matlab, but it would take too much work to do so in Qt. Seems like ligeotiff is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Currently, the TIFF image reading code in Qt skips any tags it doesn't understand. It'd be a simple fix to change that behavior, though. Build your own copy of Qt, step into the image reader code, and it should be clear what has to be changed.

Comment: Indeed, I had a look at the part you are specifying. Having my own custom built version though, even if useful in many situations, this time wont do because I am not shipping only an executable. I will have to go with libgeotiff.

Comment: Changing the internal behavior of Qt, especially private classes, is often far from trivial. And then there are the legal repercussions as well. It will definitely be easier to use a 3rd party lib. I think you could use libtiff, which is bundled with Qt, but since it doesn't support those features out of the box, you will have to manually process the tags and meta data. libgeotiff will support it directly, but you till have to build it.

Comment: @ddriver "there are the legal repercussions as well" The legal requirements on you are identical whether you distribute a modified copy of Qt or or not.